# Visual Composer custom query with OR operator

Tags: php, wordpress, visual-composer

I am working with Wordpress via Visual Composer and a post grid of results from The Events Calendar. I have the query working as long as I only want to pull from one events category but I need to pull from multiple categories.

I have tried all of the tricks using OR operators and cannot get this to work. The code I have that works to pull from one category:

```
 post_type=tribe_events&post_status=publish&_EventStartDate=>$today&orderby=_EventStartDate&order=asc&tribe_events_cat=entertainment
```

I need to pull results from Entertainment and Concerts.

Answer (score 0):

I did enough digging & learning to figure out how to use the WP_Query

```
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/
```

and how things get parsed through http_build_query

```
http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php
```

here is the solution:

```
post_type=tribe_events&post_status=publish&_EventStartDate=>$today&orderby=_EventStartDate&order=asc&include_category=(concerts,entertainment)
```